# How do i modify only 1 dimension in Unity using c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a simple game to get started with unity, there's a cube who goes straight and dodge other cubes (obstacles) which are spawned randomly. To make the obstacle always spawn in front of the player I set up a code that makes the 7 spawn position (the blocks get generated in them randomly) follow the player's coordinates but adding 100 to the Z so they get generated not upside the player. Now, my problem is that when generated the obstacle also changes their X position, making them fall from the platform when I go to the right or to the left with the player. How can I make they follow only the Z position of the player and not the X?
Here is the code that makes the spawners change position:

```
public class MoveSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position + offset;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply multiply the player's position by (0,0,1) (in other words, `Vector3.forward`) before adding it to the offset:

```
public class MoveSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Transform player;
    public Vector3 offset;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = player.position * Vector3.forward + offset;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that's pretty easy.
So if you only want to look at the Z(or any other) coordinates of the Cube or any object in Unity you can simply use:
`transform.position.z` 
That's the same thing you would do with vectors. Something like that:

```
Vector3 offset = ...;
Debug.Log(offset.x) //returns x coordinate of offset
```